# How to calculate power spectrum from mechanical vibration signal?

Tags: fft, python

I am not 100% sure if this question is fit here but it seemed the best place to post.

So my task is to perform power spectrum analysis on a signal measured with a sensor outputting movement speed of the vibration with 2 kHz rate.

So I started by doing a FFT on the measured signal and I got a array of amplitudes from which I ditched the duplicate/mirrored ones. If I remember correctly this amplitude does not present the same amplitude as found in the time domain signal. I looked my old notes and I am quite sure that I must do the following:

Assume:
amplitude from $\text{fft(signal)} = A$
$a = \text{amplitude representing the the actual movement speed}$

$$a = 2A/(\sqrt{2}N)$$
So in here I do not remember the details but I have a faint memory that half of the amplitude is lost during transfer from time domain to frequency domain and hence the multiplier of 2. The divider of $\sqrt{2}$ comes for the fact that I want to look RMS values of that signal. The other contributor in the divider is $N = \text{number of samples in signal}$. The explanation for the $N$ in this equation I do not remember but I think comes from the way DFT is performed.
This part is totally new to me and I am not sure if this is the right way to go. But this post ["Calculating 1/3 Octave Spectrum from FFT / DFT"](https://dsp.stackexchange.com/questions/46692/calculating-1-3-octave-spectrum-from-fft-dft) seemed to be at least close what I was looking for.

So the results are to be presented in $1/3$ octave band and for me that means assigning the amplitudes in frequency bins that have a length of 1/3 octave (e.g. from 112 Hz to 141 Hz)  and then summing the square of those amplitudes and then take square root from that, like:

$$ P_{total} = \sqrt{a_1^2 + a_2^2+...}$$

But again summing of the values is something I can understand but why are we summing the squares of the amplitudes?

So far so good but then I have to convert the results to decibels presenting the power of the signal. As the next step, I calculated the decibels by following:

$$ P_{db} = 2 \cdot 10 \log_{10}\left(\frac{P_{total}}{P_0}\right) $$

$P_0 = 5 \cdot 10 ^-8$ and is industry standard reference value given to me.

So in here the multiplier 10 comes from the fact we want decibels not bels. The number 2 comes from the reason that power is proportional to the square of movement speed or at least my colleagues says so. I think this is the second part of the question. While most of examples of this found on online are done in electrical domain I can agree that with electric circuits $P=UI$ and $U=IR$ --> $P=U^2/R$ and when we take the logarithm from that the exponent can be moved as a multiplier. But I simply can not get an idea how this applies to the mechanical vibrations. I just end up with:

$$W=\frac{J}{s}=\frac{Nm}{s}=\frac{kgm^2}{s^3}=\frac{kg}{s}\cdot\left(\frac{m}{s}\right)^2$$

Yes there is movement speed to the power of 2 but what is the rest $\frac{kg}{s}$ representing? I can throw a idea that of we need the mass of the vibrator which remains constant and therefore can be neglected, but for the last unit of seconds I can not think any clear way to justify it's presence in there.

So the reason I am asking is half by genuine interest of the mathematics and physical meaning of these values and half is due to the fact that I was told that the values I got as results are intuitively 20 - 40 dB too high. As I do not have anything to compare this calculation method I hoped that some one can shed a light to these unknown parts. Thanks for reading.

Comment: I don't know if I can help but ... 1)" So my task is to perform power spectrum analysis on a signal measured with a sensor outputting movement speed of the vibration with 2 kHz rate."  Let me rephrase (ask), You have a sensor that is outputting the velocity of a material (at a material sample point) _at_ a sampling rate of 2Khz?  And the "vibration" that you are attempting to calculate is peak/RMS/velocity(mm/sec) ?  The "vibration" is random/a_sine_wave/a_combination_of_harmonics_subharmonics?

Comment: In all its shortness:

- Sampling rate of the signal 2 kHz
  
- Measured quantity is movement speed [mm/s]
  
- Goals
    - To have frequency spectrum of the signal with RMS amplitudes
    - To have frequency spectrum of the signal with RMS amplitudes presented in dB with 5e-8 reference
    - To have frequency spectrum with 1/3 octave bins and with RMS amplitudes in dB with 5e-8 reference

Comment: I wanted to help you but it seems like a not very minimal question. Please consider focusing it. In case you have multiple questions, please separate them...